# Drawing constant graphs

Tags: pgfplots

I need some help with drawing constant functions.

What I want is to draw a graph of the function f(x) = C, between in the interval [a,b] where C is some arbitrary constant in the real numbers.

I have the package pgfplots, but I don't really know how to use it.

If someone could also help with piecewise constant functions, that would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Something like `\addplot[samples=2] {3};` ought to work.,  though untested.  The trick is the samples stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Here's something I had to hand:

[image]

It uses the `addplot` command as follows, for example:

```
    \addplot[cmhplot,domain=3:4]{1};
```

You'll see that I have use the `pgfplotsset` command in the preamble to set things globally.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,
                    axis y line=middle,
                    axis line style={<->},
                    xlabel={$x$},
                    ylabel={$y$},
                    line width=1pt,},
                    % line style
                    cmhplot/.style={color=blue,mark=none},
                    soldot/.style={color=blue,only marks,mark=*},
                    holdot/.style={color=blue,fill=white,only marks,mark=*},
                    % framed
                    framed/.style={axis background/.style ={draw=gray}},
                    }

% arrows
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            framed,
            xmin=-1,xmax=5,
            ymin=-1,ymax=5,
            grid=major,
            xtick={1,...,4},
            ytick={0,...,4},
        ]
    \addplot[cmhplot,domain=0:1]{4};
    \addplot[cmhplot,domain=1:2]{3};
    \addplot[cmhplot,domain=2:3]{2};
    \addplot[cmhplot,domain=3:4]{1};
    \addplot[soldot]coordinates{(0,4)(1,4)(2,2)};
    \addplot[holdot]coordinates{(1,3)(2,3)(3,2)(3,1)(4,1) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=1:3.5]{4.23};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]